# `.tickFormat(d3.format("s"))` error: y-axis tick labels don't display

Tags: d3.js

I was trying Curran's splitting charts examples and noticed that all charts starting [from the 4th one](http://curran.github.io/screencasts/splittingCharts/examples/viewer/#/4) don't display y-axis tick texts.

I have updated my chrome to the latest version(Version 51.0.2704.106 (64-bit)). but still could not see the y-axis tick texts as the following picture demonstrated:

[image]

I think it was due to `.tickFormat(d3.format("s"))` as when comment out this line of code, we can see y-axis tick texts.

Was this error due to my Chrome browser? or something is changed in the version of d3.js or something else?

Could anyone give me some idea on how to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: It displays for me.

Comment: Thanks! Could you tell me the version of Chrome you are using?

Comment: I'm using 51.0.2704.103 m. Windows 64bits. I can see "2B, 4B, 6B" in the y axis.

Comment: I am using Mac. I tried FireFox browser, everything is good. y-axis text display properly. So, I guess it has nothing to do with codes, but google chrome's problem on Mac?

Comment: Yes, I'd say that's a Chrome on Mac bug.

Comment: Thanks, now I use Firefox for running those examples, it solves the problems

Comment: But it would be interesting to report that bug (if it is a bug) to Chrome developers.